# grouping words by first character

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**What I have:** A text-file which is read line by line. Each String contains a line.

**What I want:** Group ALL words by first character using Java Streams.

**What I have so far:**

```
public static Map<Character, List<String>> groupByFirstChar(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    return Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH)).
            flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("[^a-zA-Z]"))).
            map(s -> s.toLowerCase()).
            sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2)).
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0)));
}
```

**Problem:** I get an Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:646)
at textana.TextAnalysisFns.lambda$16(TextAnalysisFns.java:110)
at textana.TextAnalysisFns$$Lambda$36/159413332.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$196(Collectors.java:907)
at java.util.stream.Collectors$$Lambda$23/189568618.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink$$Lambda$37/186370029.accept(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:390)
at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:258)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:513)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at textana.TextAnalysisFns.groupByFirstChar(TextAnalysisFns.java:110)
at textana.SampleTextAnalysisApp.main(SampleTextAnalysisApp.java:95)
```

**Question:** Why do I get a StringIndexOutOfBoundException ?

**Solution based on the hints in the comments:**

```
public static Map<Character, List<String>> groupByFirstChar(String fileName)
        throws IOException {

    return Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH)).
            flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("[^a-zA-Z]"))).
            filter(s -> s.length() > 0).
            map(s -> s.toLowerCase()).
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0)));
}
```

The Solution of User Eran would have given me the empty Strings in the beginning which I didn't want to have.

Comment: By the way you can skip the argument of sorted() operation, as you are using natural ordering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try filtering empty strings `""` since they have no first character which is causing `charAt(0)` to throw this exception.

You can use

```
flatMap(s -> Stream.of(s.split("[^a-zA-Z]"))).
filter(s -> !s.trim().isEmpty()). //add this line
```

BTW your method should probably use its `fileName` argument. So maybe consider changing `Paths.get(PATH)` into something more like

```
Paths.get(fileName).
```

or

```
Paths.get(PATH).resolve(fileName)
```

Also as already mentioned by comment since you are not changing default comparison order you don't need to explicitly write

```
sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareTo(s2))
```

but simple

```
sorted()
```

will work as well since default order will be applied here.

---

As mentioned by [@Alexis C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587046/alexis-c) groupBy will return `HashMap` which means that your keys will not be ordered. If you would also like to preserve their order you can use groupBy with `LinkedHashMap` like

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: You can even remove the `sorted`, as `groupingBy` uses an `HashMap` behind the scenes so the notion of ordering is lost anyway.

Comment: @AlexisC. We will lose only order of keys, but values in `List<String>` should stay ordered if I am not mistaken, which may be what OP tries to achieve here.

Comment: @AlexisC. No problem, that was interesting observation which kind of make me think about solution which will also save order of keys. I am working on `Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), LinkedHashMap::new, ???)` but need to learn what to put in `???` part :)

Comment: `groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), LinkedHashMap::new, toList())` since you want to accumulate the values in a `List`

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have an empty line at the end of your file, perhaps silently added by your text editor, that makes the last `s.charAt(0)` fail.

Hint about how to detect it: in the stack trace, read `collect` and `lambda$16`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 s.charAt(0)
```

Check s is null before executing this instruction in order to  avoid the Exception.